# .Net MongoDB Driver Subcollection, Builders, and Projections

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

(Forgive my newbiness.) If given the following classes how would you

1. Query on a property of a subcollection. (Avoiding strings as much as possible)
2. Project and map the result to the given DTO?

Classes:

```
public class Customer{

    public ObjectId Id;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    .
    .   
    . (Other Properties specific to the customer profile)
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions;
}

public class Transaction{
    public ObjectId ItemId;
    public DateTime PurchaseDate;
    .
    .
    . (etc.)
}

public class TransactionDTO{
    public ObjectId CustomerId;
    public string FirstName;
    public ObjectId ItemId;
    public DateTime PurchaseDate; 
}
```

Aside from any compile issues there might be, is this the wrong/right approach to mongo?

How would I get a list of transactions where ItemId == x projected to the TransactionDTO using the Builders class provided in the mongo Driver.

This is where I'm headed but I've run into some road blocks.

to query the main collection (Customer) on a specific property you can build the query like this:

```
Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(c=>c.firstname,"Bob");
```

but using this syntax I can't query on the subcollection.

```
Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(c=>c.Transactions....????, "match condition");
```

so what is the proper way to be able to query? Similarly the projection would look something like this:

```
Builders<Customer>.Projection.Expression(c=> new TransactionDTO(){
    CustomerId = x.Id,
    FirstName = x.FirstName, // <- these should be fine.
    itemId = x.Transaction...???
    PurchaseDate = x.Transaction....???
})
```

[Mongo C# Docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the use of an aggregate. Using the Collection you should be able to do something similar to the following

Assuming you have the following classes and want to map into MainWithSub

```
public class MainClass
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string PropOne { get; set; }
    public string PropTwo { get; set; }
    public List<SubClass> subClasses { get; set; }
}
public class SubClass
{
    public string PropThree { get; set; }
}

public class MainWithSub
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string PropOne { get; set; }
    public string PropTwo { get; set; }
    public string PropThree { get; set; }
}
```

you can then make the following call with your collection

```
Collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(t => t.Id == new ObjectId())
            .Unwind<MainClass, MainWithSub>(t => t.subClasses)
            .Match(t => t.PropThree == "filter");
```

this will return you a list of MainWithSub ( a flattened version) classes filtered in the on propthree

Comment: This is correct but doesn't answer the complexity of the question. I have an array of objects stored inside the main collection that I'm trying to match on. which could return many of the "MainClass" Objects. after I have the results I want to map it to a third class. which is only difficult because of the array of objects. conceptually I'm unwinding the objects, then querying on a property of the unwound object then mapping it to a new class that has properties from both the object inside the array and the object containing the array.